# GANs output is 64x64x3 instead of 256x256x3

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have a GANs code for generating images using TensorFlow, the discriminator and the generator are coded to output an image of 256x256x3 but I am getting 64x64x3.

My code implemented code is:

**Discriminator Creation:**
It maps a 256x256 image to a binary classification score.

```
img_size = 256
discriminator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(img_size, img_size, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(512, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.3),
        layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="discriminator",
)
```

**Generator Creation:**
It mirrors the discriminator, replacing Conv2D layers with Conv2DTranspose layers.

```
latent_dim = 128

generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,)),
        layers.Dense(16 * 16 * 128),
        layers.Reshape((16, 16, 128)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(1024, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
        name="generator",
        )
```

**Override train_step:**

```
class GAN(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.generator = generator
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super().compile()
        self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
        self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
        self.loss_fn = loss_fn
        self.d_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="d_loss")
        self.g_loss_metric = keras.metrics.Mean(name="g_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.d_loss_metric, self.g_loss_metric]

    def train_step(self, real_images):
        # Sample random points in the latent space
        batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Decode them to fake images
        generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors)

        # Combine them with real images
        combined_images = tf.concat([generated_images, real_images], axis=0)

        # Assemble labels discriminating real from fake images
        labels = tf.concat(
            [tf.ones((batch_size, 1)), tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))], axis=0
        )
        # Add random noise to the labels - important trick!
        labels += 0.05 * tf.random.uniform(tf.shape(labels))

        # Train the discriminator
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(combined_images)
            d_loss = self.loss_fn(labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        )

        # Sample random points in the latent space
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))

        # Assemble labels that say "all real images"
        misleading_labels = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))

        # Train the generator (note that we should *not* update the weights
        # of the discriminator)!
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(self.generator(random_latent_vectors))
            g_loss = self.loss_fn(misleading_labels, predictions)
        grads = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_weights)
        self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.generator.trainable_weights))

        # Update metrics
        self.d_loss_metric.update_state(d_loss)
        self.g_loss_metric.update_state(g_loss)
        return {
            "d_loss": self.d_loss_metric.result(),
            "g_loss": self.g_loss_metric.result(),
        }
```

**Creating a callback that periodically saves generated images**

```
!mkdir 'training_checkpoints/'


class GANMonitor(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, num_img=3, latent_dim=128):
        self.num_img = num_img
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        checkpoint_dir = 'training_checkpoints/'
        checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
        checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_optimizer=self.model.g_optimizer,
                                        discriminator_optimizer=d_optimizer,
                                        generator=generator,
                                        discriminator=discriminator)
        random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(self.num_img, self.latent_dim))
        generated_images = self.model.generator(random_latent_vectors)
        generated_images *= 255
        generated_images.numpy()
        # Save the model every 15 epochs
        if (epoch + 1) % 15 == 0:
          checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

        for i in range(self.num_img):
            img = keras.utils.array_to_img(generated_images[i])
            img.save("generated_img_%03d_%d.png" % (epoch, i))
```

**Training the end-to-end model:**

```
epochs = 100 

gan = GAN(discriminator=discriminator, generator=generator, latent_dim=latent_dim)
gan.compile(
    d_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    g_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss_fn=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
)
gan.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[GANMonitor(num_img=10, latent_dim=latent_dim)], use_multiprocessing = True)
```

Now this code is slower and it generate 64x64x3 images instead of 256x256x3, and when I change the code to generate 64x64x3 it takes less time and it generate of course 64x64x3 images.

**My 64x64x3 code for the generator and discriminator:**

```
discriminator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dropout(0.2),
        layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="discriminator",
)
```

```
generator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,)),
        layers.Dense(16 * 16 * 128),
        layers.Reshape((16, 16, 128)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(512, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(1024, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
        layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding="same", activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
        name="generator",
        )
```

Comment: Can you please share how you confirmed that you got 64 x 64 x 3 images? Looking at the generator code it looks properly coded to output 256 x 256 x 3.